# Does ForEach-Object operate on a single object in the pipeline or on a collection of objects?

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I've had trouble grasping how the PowerShell pipeline works and I realise a lot of the problem is due to `ForEach-Object`.  In other languages I've used, foreach operates on a collection, iterating through each element of the collection in turn.  I assumed `ForEach-Object`, when used in a PowerShell pipeline, would do the same.  However, everything I read about the pipeline suggests each element of a collection is passed through the pipeline separately and that downstream cmdlets are called repeatedly, operating on each element separately rather than on the collection as a whole.

So does `ForEach-Object` operate on a single element in the collection, rather than on the collection as a whole?  Looking at it a different way, does the pipeline operator pass through the whole collection to `ForEach-Object`, which then iterates over it, or does the pipeline object iterate over the collection and pass each element separately to `ForEach-Object`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **`ForEach-Object` cmdlet** - unlike the `foreach` *statement* - itself **performs *no* enumeration**.

Instead, it operates on each item passed through the pipeline (with the option to also execute code before receiving the first and after receiving the last item, if any).

Therefore, it is arguably poorly named, given that **it is the *pipeline* that provides the enumeration** (by default), and that `ForEach-Object` simply invokes a script block for each item received.

The following examples illustrate this:

```
# Let the pipeline enumerate the elements of an array:
> 1, 2 | ForEach-Object { "item: [$_]; count: $($_.Count)" }
item: [1]; count: 1
item: [2]; count: 1

# Send the array *as a whole* through the pipeline (PSv4+)
> Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2 | ForEach-Object { "item: [$_]; count: $($_.Count)" }
item: [1 2]; count: 2
```

---

Note that **scripts / functions / cmdlets can *choose* whether a collection they write to the output stream (pipeline) should be enumerated** or sent as a whole (as a single object).

In PowerShell code (scripts or functions, whether advanced (cmdlet-like) or not, enumeration is the default, but you can opt out with **`Write-Output -NoEnumerate`**; the `-NoEnumerate` switch was introduced in PSv4; prior to that, you had to use **`$PSCmdlet.WriteObject()`**, which is only available to *advanced* scripts / functions.

Also note that **embedding a command in an *expression* by enclosing it in `(...)` forces enumeration**:

```
# Send array as a whole.
> Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2 | Measure-Object

Count: 1
...

# Converting the Write-Output -NoEnumerate command to an expression
# by enclosing it in in (...) forces enumeration
> (Write-Output -NoEnumerate 1, 2) | Measure-Object

Count: 2
...
```

Answer (score 3):

`ForEach-Object` iterates through each item in a collection. When it is done performing it's scriptblock on the current item it is sent down the pipeline to the next command which can then immediately start processing it (while the `ForEach-Object` is dealing with the next item if there is one).

You can see this in action in the following example:

```
Get-Process | ForEach-Object { Start-Sleep 1; $_ } | Format-Table
```

The `Get-Process` cmdlet gets a list of processes and immediately sends each to `ForEach-Object` one at a time. The `ForEach-Object` is waiting 1 second and then outputting the current pipeline element `$_`. This is received by `Format-Table` which outputs it as a table. You can see it doesn't wait until all of the Processes are processed before outputting to the screen.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is...kind of both.

A PowerShell function which supports pipelining (an advanced function) will *process* each item coming through the pipeline individually. It can also define a `begin` and `end` block which will be executed only once in a pipeline stage. In other words, the basic structure is this:

```
function Do-Stuff {
    begin {
         write-output "This will be done once, at the beginning"
    }
    process {
      Write-output "This will be done for each item"
    }
    end {
        Write-output "This will be done once, at the end"
    }
}
```

The output of `1..3 | foreach-Object {Do-Stuff $_}` will be:

```
This will be done once, at the beginning
This will be done for each item
This will be done for each item
This will be done for each item
This will be done once, at the end
```

Because `Do-Stuff` is writing to the output stream, if there are additional pipeline stages *after* this `Foreach-Object`, each object output will be passed on to the next stage in turn. If there aren't any further stages or anything else to capture output, the output stream will be written to the console.

For example:

```
$verbosepreference = "continue";
[int]1..3|foreach-object {write-output $_; write-verbose ($_*-1)}|foreach-object {$_*$_;write-verbose $_}
```

Gives the following output:

```
1
VERBOSE: 1
VERBOSE: -1
4
VERBOSE: 2
VERBOSE: -2
9
VERBOSE: 3
VERBOSE: -3
```

`-X` is output to the Verbose stream last (for each item) because the output was passed on to the next stage of the pipeline and processed *before* the next statement in the `foreach-object` scriptblock was executed.

Comment: A quick aside: `[int]1..3` is the same as `([int]1) .. 3`, which is the same as just `1..3`, given that the result of a range-operator expression is _always_ a ( `[System.Object[]]`) array with `[int]` elements.
Number literals such as `1` and `3` are `[int]`-typed anyway, but even if they weren't, PowerShell would simply coerce them implicitly; e.g.,`'1' .. '3'` would yield the same result.